# How to subscribe to swap events for 0x protocol?

Tags: 0x

I'm building an nft marketplace and I'm getting the data from reservoir. I have built swap/trade functionality using 0x on my marketplace. I want to now subscribe to swap events on my marketplace. Is there an option to subscribe to such events on 0x?

Answer (score 0):

When setting up the event listener, you can specify filters to only capture "Fill" events related to your marketplace. You can filter by specific tokens, pairs, or any other criteria relevant to your platform. Whether you're a seasoned pro with a treasure trove of casino tales or a newbie looking for tips to enhance your gaming skills, this space is open to everyone. From jaw-dropping slot machine wins to mastering the art of card counting,  https://whizzcasinos.com/hu/valodi-penzes-nyerogepek

Comment: @maconganzles that is fine. I'm asking which endpoint should I connect the event listener to? I'm creating a bot that posts updates about swaps on discord channels. I want it to have the ability to span multiple marketplaces. Since reservoir does not offer an endpoint to provide swap related info I wanted to know if 0x did that?